# Alert being thrown before the console.log("outside the .then" + this.result); gets printed

Tags: javascript

Why my alert is being thrown before I can print `console.log("outside the .then" + this.result);`?
The result is true, my `this.result = Admin_product`

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    this.oktaAuthService.getUser().then(
      (res) => {
        this.result = res.groups.find((group) => group === 'Admin_product');
        console.log("inside the .then" + (this.result))
      }
    )
    if (this.result === 'Admin_product') {
      console.log("outside the .then" + this.result);
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('User is not authorized to perform this operation');
      return false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: You should not have expected otherwise, you don't _await_ the promise. Read the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761.

Comment: ah thank you for your response I do not have much knowledge about promises

Comment: The promise callback (in the `then(...)`) is exectued after the synchronous part of the function is ended, so after your `alert` and `return false`.